# Add service reference error after try to connect my WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

My WCF service app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceHosting.Injector">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WCFServiceHosting.IInjector">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8523/Injector" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

i installed this service on my machine and this service start successfully.
in my solution i have also `winform application` and after try to `Add service reference` an error occurs:

> The URI prefix is not recognized.
>
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://192.168.0.199:8523/Injector'.
>
> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:04:59.9989974'.
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

i also disable my `firewall` and try to change ip 0.0.0.0 to my machine `ip address` or change it to `localhost` but still same error.